# Rotating object around multiple axes using glm::mat4

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, shader, glm-math

I'm trying to apply multiple rotations around x,y,z axis to an object by using glm::rotate method but for some reason it only rotates around one axis and seems to be completely ignoring other rotations.
Here is how I apply rotation:

```
glm::mat4 rotateTransform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
rotateTransform = glm::rotate(rotateTransform, this->rotation.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
rotateTransform = glm::rotate(rotateTransform, this->rotation.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
rotateTransform = glm::rotate(rotateTransform, this->rotation.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));

return glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), this->position) * rotateTransform *   glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), this->scale);
```

the method returns modelToWorldMatrix which I then pass to my vertexShader where I perform standart calculation on a vertex:

```
vec4 vertexPositionInModelSpace = vec4(Position, 1);
vec4 vertexInWorldSpace = gModelToWorldTransform * vertexPositionInModelSpace;
vec4 vertexInViewSpace = gWorldToViewTransform * vertexInWorldSpace;
vec4 vertexInHomogeneousClipSpace = gProjectionTransform * vertexInViewSpace;
gl_Position = vertexInHomogeneousClipSpace;
```

So how can you apply multiple rotations by using glm::mat4 matrices?

Comment: are all this->rotation.x, y and z non zero values? Around which axis does it rotate? ( Keep in mind that 3 rotations of 90 degrees around the 3 standard axis will look as if you only rotated around 1 axis ).

Comment: yes, some of them are 0-s(Depending on rotation). Can that be an issue ?

Comment: Well a rotation of 0 degrees around an axis does nothing. What are you getting and what do you expect. A snapshot always helps understanding the problem.